# How to save screenshot both to clipboard and disk?

Tags: command-line, bash, clipboard

I am trying achieve such behavior that screenshot is saved both to the disk and to clipboard. Been digging through these questions, but it's not coming together.

[What is the terminal command to take a screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194427/what-is-the-terminal-command-to-take-a-screenshot)
[What is the command line equivalent of copying a file to clipboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210413/what-is-the-command-line-equivalent-of-copying-a-file-to-clipboard)

Main problem being that I can't really copy the image to the clipboard to paste it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
Is there anything else I might want to consider ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank both @vanadium and @pLumo for their answers, which were very helpful, but both of used utilities have their own disadvantages and bugs at least on my system, so I finally went with combination of two approaches

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

OUT_FILENAME=Screenshot from $(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").png
OUT_PATH=~/Pictures/$OUT_FILENAME

gnome-screenshot -a -f $OUT_PATH
xclip -sel clip < /dev/null
xclip -selection clip -t image/png $OUT_PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the `xclip` command to `scrot -e`:

```bsh
scrot '%F_%T.png' -e 'xclip -selection clip -t image/png "$f"; mv "$f" ~/Desktop/'
```

Of course you don't need to move the file to the Desktop, it's just an example how to combine multiple commands ...

You might need to install `scrot`:

```
sudo apt install scrot
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! But I'm not getting what -b ( grab wm border too ) does

Comment: Probably you can simply leave it out ... Might be useful for themes with window borders when you just grab a single window ;-) Copied it from [one of the answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/194438/631600) you linked.

Comment: Turned out, this does not always work, when bound to a shortuct for some reason, and also there is a chance of framing getting in the way

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use the default Ubuntu desktop, just combine two options of the `gnome-screenshot` command for sending to the clipboard and to a file:

```
gnome-screenshot -c -f file.png
```

This will send the output to the clipboard and to a file, in this example in your Pictures folder, named according to the timestamp given by the `date -Ins` command.

Comment: `gnome-screenshot` would be ideal, but -c and -f don't seem to work together for me, file is not being saved with -c present

Comment: @Yury so maybe just `gnome-screenshot -c && gnome-screenshot -f filename` ?

Comment: I noted I forgot a / and an extension. Try the updated command. Files of your previous attempt will be in your current working directory, name starting with Pictures, but without extension.

Comment: Tested this also on 20.04 now.

Comment: With just 2 repeated calls to 'gnome-screenshot' with -a option one would have to select area twice.

Comment: I'm using 18.04.05  with `gnome-screenshot is already the newest version (3.25.0-0ubuntu2)` and -c option prevents file from saving anywhere

Comment: @vanadium Could you specify your version of `gnome-screenshot` ? Maybe I can try it instead

Comment: The version that comes with Ubuntu 20.04.